# $P(x,y) = n$ iff $n$ is NOT a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

Does there exist a two variable polynomial $P(X,Y)$ with integer coefficients such that a positive integer $n$ is a perfect square iff there **do not** exists a tuple $(X,Y)$ of positive integers such that $P(X,Y)= n$ ?

Spoiler:

> There does exists a three variable polynomial $P(X,Y,Z)$ such that an integer $n$ is a perfect square iff there **do not** exists a tuple $(X,Y,Z)$ of positive integers such that $P(X,Y,Z) = n$. This extremely tricky construction appeared in [USA 2013 IMO TST P8](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h546349p3161954) (see the thread for two constructions). On that thread a certain user raises the question about the nonexistence of such polynomial for two-variable cases, but since that's not answered there I'm asking it here.

Comment: http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/nonsquares.pdf might be relevant.

Comment: Have you had a look at that reference, alxchen?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for the reference, but unfortunately I'm a high school student and I don't know anything of algebraic number theory/algebraic geometry. The entire paper is over my head. I was asking for some possible elementary density arguements that would disprove the two varialbe case or some very clever elementary construction.

Comment: Would've been helpful to have put that information in the body of the question. Anyway, given how tricky the 3-variable solution is, I'm guessing there's no simple answer for the 2-variable problem.

Comment: @GerryMyerson By the way, is the papers you linked understandable with basic knowledge of ANT? I'm planning to study some elementary ANT topics from October from Ireland Rosen with Murthy for the problems.

Comment: I suspect it's going to take more than that. And not just ANT, but some algebraic geometry, and some logic.